# How to name a deployment done via Metadata API?

Tags: deployment, change-set

When we deploy the code changes using changesets, we can see the name of the deployment. [image]

The picture is not very clear, but you can see the Docusign changes. How can we name our deployments when doing so via metadata API ?

Comment: I meant to say "see the name in Deployment status", not settings.

Comment: This is currently not possible with the Metadata API but there is a Salesforce [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cJdxAAE) you can promote to add this functionality. Note: the `<fullName>` XML element in the package.xml file will not set the deploy Name.

Comment: Still not possible..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with just Metadata deployment. If you are using other tools like git and Jenkins you can easily see the components you are trying to deploy and their history (still not in Salesforce, but you have auditing / history tracking capability).

Comment: This answer does not answer my question.

Comment: I don't think this can be done is the answer to your question. I suggested other workaround. There is no need to give -be reputation if someone is trying to help. Thx anyway