# Give a name to deployment via the Metadata API?

Tags: metadata-api

It's been 5 years since a similar [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94225/how-to-name-a-deployment-done-via-metadata-api) was asked, I was wondering if anything changed since then and if we can name a deployment made by the Metadata API?

Comment: I don't think the answer has changed and the question is not materially different, so will likely tag this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I didn't want to comment on the original question because no one would have seen it.

Comment: That's what bounties are for.

Answer (score 0):

It's still not possible. I would rather apply some releasing notation or git tagging within your repository